# Azure Ghost Login Redirect

Tags: azure, ghost-blog

Whenever I browse my blog which I created via Azure marketplace for Ghost with completely default settings, I get redirected to a login page.

If I log in then I get taken back. I can click my post and be taken to the content. If I then go back, then click the heading again, it takes me to the edit area.

The problem I have is that readers of the blog are being prompted to login. I don't want this. I just want my content to appear when they click a post.

Anybody else experienced this or know what I can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear this is only the behavior on the default post that is created once you have activated the service.

Once you start making posts and unpublish the initial one, it behaves as expected. Hopefully this helps clear up any confusion for someone else.